# Cohomology of submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, submanifold, manifolds-with-boundary, de-rham-cohomology

Suppose I have a manifold $M$ and a submanifold or a boundary $N\subset M$. By the natural inclusion $\iota:N\hookrightarrow M$ we can easily see that
$$\omega\in\mathrm{H}^k(M) \quad\implies\quad \iota^*\omega\in\mathrm{H}^k(N).$$

On the other hand, obviously
$$\iota^*\omega\in\mathrm{H}^k(N) \quad\not\kern{-0.5em}\implies\quad \omega\in\mathrm{H}^k(M).$$

Is there something to be said about those forms that are in the cohomology of $N$ but not in that of $M$? Precisely, does either the space
$$\mathrm{Hmm}_{(1)}^k(N,M):=\left\lbrace\omega\in\mathrm{H}^k(N)\ \middle|\ \omega\neq\iota^*\eta,\quad \eta\in\mathrm{H}^k(M)\right\rbrace$$
or the space
$$ \mathrm{Hmm}_{(2)}^k(N,M) := \mathrm{H}^k(N)\Big/\left\lbrace\omega\in\mathrm{H}^k(N)\ \middle|\ \omega=\iota^*\eta,\quad \eta\in\mathrm{H}^k(M)\right\rbrace$$
have a simple description?<sup>1</sup> I have a hunch that it should come from some relative cohomology but I wasn't able to make it precise. Even if there is no simple description, can we say something about its dimension?

I am more interested in the case where $N=\partial M$ (so if there's something to be said there but not in the general case, I'm perfectly happy), but the general case seems interesting too.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>I'm writing both spaces to maximize my chances, see the helpful comments of @Thorgott and @Osama Ghani</sup>

Comment: This seems imprecise to me. I think you want to talk about cocycles, not cohomology classes?

Comment: I think you've asked a couple of inequivalent things here. Maybe what you mean to ask is given $N \subset M$, can you describe $\{\omega = H^k(N) | \omega \neq i^*\eta, \eta \in H^k(M) \}$

Comment: In general though, all smooth manifolds admit partitions of unity. So, if there is an open set about the submanifold $N$ then using a partition of unity, you can extend any differential form from $N$ to the whole manifold by $0$. In particular, the boundary of a manifold has a collar neighbourhood that is open in $M$.

Comment: @OsamaGhani thanks, yeah, this is closer to what I'm looking for. Added that in now. I don't understand what the implication of your other comment is though.

Comment: @Thorgott well, I would like to bunch them in classes so I want to talk about cohomology classes. Maybe indeed it's imprecisely written, but I don't want to talk about cocycles.

Comment: I still don't understand what $\iota^*\omega\in\mathrm{H}^k(N) \quad\not\kern{-0.5em}\implies\quad \omega\in\mathrm{H}^k(M)$ is supposed to mean. Where does $\omega$ live a priori so that writing $\iota^*\omega\in\mathrm{H}^k(N)$ makes sense to begin with? Also, instead of the complement of the image, I think your chances to describe the quotient of $H^k(N)$ by the image of $H^k(M)$ are much better (just algebraically already).

Comment: @Thorgott I mean $[\omega]$ and $[\iota^*\omega]$, with $\omega\in\Omega^k(M)$. I'll add the space back in to maximize my chances then.

Comment: Well, for a form to define a cohomology class, you want it to be a cocycle. That's where my first comment came from. Anyway, the restriction map $\Omega^{\ast}(M)\rightarrow\Omega^{\ast}(N)$ is surjective (why?), so if we let $\Omega^{\ast}(M,N)$ be its kernel, this is also a chain complex and we have a SES of chain complexes $0\rightarrow\Omega^{\ast}(M,N)\rightarrow\Omega^{\ast}(M)\rightarrow\Omega^{\ast}(N)\rightarrow0$. The associated LES in cohomology describes your $Hmm_{(2)}$. You can google "relative de Rham cohomology" for alternative descriptions of this concept.

Comment: @Thorgott is right, relative de Rham cohomology is exactly what you're looking for—there's even an account in Bott and Tu.

Comment: Well, yes, surely I want it to be a cocycle (but, as said earlier I wanted to bunch them up in classes). As for the relative de Rham cohomology, perfect, I guess my hunch was correct then :). I'd be grateful if you could write up as an answer how the LES in cohmomology describes $\mathrm{Hmm}_{(2)}$, thanks!

Comment: TL;DR: you get a long exact sequence $\cdots \to H^k(M,N) \to H^k(M) \xrightarrow{\iota^\ast} H^k(N) \to H^{k+1}(M,N) \to \cdots$, so that the range of $\iota^\ast : H^k(M) \to H^k(N)$ is the kernel of the connecting homomorphism $H^k(N) \to H^{k+1}(M,N)$ and the kernel of $\iota^\ast : H^k(M) \to H^k(N)$ is the range of the map $H^k(M,N) \to H^k(M)$ induced by the inclusion $\Omega^k(M,N) \to \Omega^k(M)$.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Sure, this tells me how to get the LES from the SES. What I don't see is how this describes $\mathrm{Hmm}_{(2)}$.

Comment: Your $\operatorname{Hmm}_{(2)}$ is the cokernel of $\iota^\ast : H^k(M) \to H^k(N)$. In general, suppose that $T : V \to W$ is a linear map between finite-dimensional vector spaces, so that its cokernel is $\operatorname{coker}(T) := V/\operatorname{ran}(T)$. Then, by the rank-nullity theorem,
$$
 \dim \operatorname{coker}(T) = \dim W - \dim \operatorname{ran}(T) = (\dim W - \dim V) + \dim\ker(T).
$$

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Cool, and then I'll read the dimension of the kernel by making repeated use of the LES until I hit a zero, right? One final thing that I'm missing is the dimension of $\mathrm{H}^k(M,N)$. (Also there is a typo, I guess you meant $W/\mathrm{ran}(T)$)